# Gradle Build failed on using proguard

Tags: android, proguard, phonegap-build, stack-trace, phonegap

I am using proguard plugin, googleplus plugin and push notification plugin. On building the app using Phonegap Build it outputs the following stacktrace :

```
Warning: there were 845 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 112 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details**

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.



:app:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileReleaseSources
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:mergeReleaseShaders
:app:compileReleaseShaders
:app:generateReleaseAssets
:app:mergeReleaseAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles
:app:extractTryWithResourcesSupportJarRelease
:app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForRelease
:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForRelease
:app:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease
ProGuard, version 5.3.3
Reading input...
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/0.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/2.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/3.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/4.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/5.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/6.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/7.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/8.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/9.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/10.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/11.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/12.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/13.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/14.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/15.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/16.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/17.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/18.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/19.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/20.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/21.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/22.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/23.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/24.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/25.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/26.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/27.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/28.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/29.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/30.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/31.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/32.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/33.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/34.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/35.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/36.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/37.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/38.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/39.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/40.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/41.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/42.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/43.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/44.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/45.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/46.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/47.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/48.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/49.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/50.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/51.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/52.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/53.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/54.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/55.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/56.jar] (filtered)
Reading program directory [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/1] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/processing-tools/runtime-deps/release/desugar_try_with_resources.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJavaRes/release/0.jar] (filtered)
Reading library jar [/opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar]
Reading library jar [/opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-26/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpParams]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.HostNameResolver]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate$DName]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.HttpResponseCache]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslError]
Note: there were 11 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Initializing...
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.facebook.messaging.analytics.reliability.ReliabilityInfo'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.facebook.messaging.analytics.reliability.ReliabilityInfo.Outcome'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult$ReleasableResultGuardian'
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.AccountChangeEvent: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.AccountChangeEventsRequest: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.AccountChangeEventsResponse: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.TokenData: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.account.zzb: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzee
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.account.zzd: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzee
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.account.zze: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzed
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.account.zzg: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbo
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.AccountTransferClient$zzb: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzdf
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.DeviceMetaData: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.Credential: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.CredentialPickerConfig: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.CredentialRequest: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.HintRequest: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.IdToken: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.PasswordSpecification: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.proxy.ProxyRequest: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.proxy.ProxyResponse: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient$zza: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbo
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.SignInAccount: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzb: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzcx
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzd: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzab
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzr: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzee
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzt: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzee
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzv:Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzs: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbem
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzs: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfl
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzs: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfl
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzs: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfl
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzs: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfl
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzs: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfl
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzs: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfl
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzs: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfl
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzt: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbek
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzt: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbek
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzt: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbek
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzt: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbek
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzt: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbek
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzt: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbek
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzt: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbel
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzt: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbel
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzu: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbem
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzu: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbem
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzu: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbem
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzu: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbem
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzu: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbem
Warning: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.accounttransfer.zzu: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbem
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to search for proguard rules for these libraries and add them in your proguard-rules.pro file. You can easily find these rules on google

Comment: The build fails when I add cordova-plugin-firebase.